# How do I pass the value of environment variable into the remote command arguments?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I am learning gitlab ci/cd and my ci assignment has this script in it:

```
ssh $REMOTE_SERVER_ADDRESS '(docker stop $(docker ps -q -f ancestor=$CI_PROJECT_NAME))) && echo CONTAINER $CI_PROJECT_NAME STOPPED || echo $CI_PROJECT_NAME NOT FOUND'
```

To clarify.

I haven't found how gitlab can connect to ssh without terminating the session, so I have to make connections time after time and execute commands.

$VARIABLE - gitlab environment variables.

I need to pass an environment variable in the arguments to the remote command.

`ssh $REMOTE_SERVER_ADDRESS ' ....... '` - if I use single quotes, I'm running the command remotely and I don't have access to environment variables, except for one option I found, but more on that later.

`ssh $REMOTE_SERVER_ADDRESS " ....... "` - if you use double quotes, the command is executed locally and variables are picked up.

After googling the problem, I found the only solution in different variations that somehow works:

`ssh docker-user@192.168.100.3 test=docker-ci-cd 'printenv test'` - I get my variable

`ssh docker-user@192.168.100.3 test=docker-ci-cd 'echo $test'` - I get empty output

I tried passing in arguments like this, but it didn't work:

`ssh docker-user@192.168.100.3 test=docker-ci-cd 'docker ps -f ancestor=$(printenv test)'`

How do I pass the value of this environment variable into the remote command arguments? - If it is even created on the remote server, I'm not sure yet, but the env output suggests that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass an environment variable to a remote command in SSH, you need to make sure the variable is expanded on the local machine *before* the command is sent to the remote server. That can be achieved by using double quotes instead of single quotes, as [double quotes allow variable expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27701642/6309).

```bash
Local Machine (GitLab CI Runner)                Remote Machine (SSH Server)
-----------------------------                   --------------------------
|                           |                   |                        |
| $CI_PROJECT_NAME variable | -- SSH Command -> | Execute Docker Command |
| (e.g., your Docker image) |                   |                        |
|                           |                   |                        |
-----------------------------                   --------------------------
```

Your original command should be modified to use double quotes for the SSH command so that `$CI_PROJECT_NAME` is expanded before the command is sent to the remote server.

```bash
ssh $REMOTE_SERVER_ADDRESS "docker stop \$(docker ps -q -f ancestor=$CI_PROJECT_NAME) && echo CONTAINER $CI_PROJECT_NAME STOPPED || echo $CI_PROJECT_NAME NOT FOUND"
```

Escape the `$` in `$(docker ps -q -f ancestor=$CI_PROJECT_NAME)` with a backslash (`\`) to prevent it from being expanded on the local machine. That way, `docker ps` command runs *remotely*.

Comment: Yes, it's called shielding, solved the problem that way, thanks!